# Would a map's put need synchronization if all keys are unique?

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronization

Lets assume a scenario where "keys" would never overlap, but be unique for an application. In other words each put will `never` be called for same key. In such a case :

1. Would synchronization be required for map.put ?
2. If yes, then how ?

For example, let assume a case of `<Name, Id>` and in an imaginary world, everyones name is unique.
In such an application, would I need to synchronize map put ?

Comment: Could you clarify question with more details..

Comment: `each put will be called for same key` ?

Comment: The question isn't really answerable, because Map is an abstract type (actually an interface), and that doesn't tell you anything about its implementation.  Some implementations may require synchronization, but I think it's possible to develop an implementation that doesn't (or that does its own synchronization).  Do you mean a `HashMap` in particular?

Comment: @ajb i meant hashmap as hastables are synchorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  For example: a `put()` on a new key can cause a `resize()` on the map - two simultaneous `resize()` calls can cause the internals of the data structure to become inconsistent.  Inconsistent can mean things such as (actually witnessed) causing subsequent calls to `put()` to loop infinitely, because it left internal references inconsistent and created a loop.

Comment: Very useful, now is resize the `only` reason for synchronization in case described above ?

Comment: What will break depends on what map implementation you're using. Resize is the most obvious thing (because I just fixed a breakage caused by this exact problem), but consider what happens with e.g. HashMap when you do two `put()` calls for keys that have the same hash - even if the keys aren't the same, they may still be writing to the same slot.

Comment: Very clear and wish I could accept it multiple times - big help for a long held doubt of mine. Thanks,

Comment: @JavaDeveloper While you've asked an interesting question, my take on it is: the contract (in the javadoc) says you have to synchronize externally when using `HashMap`, so you should just trust it.  Even if you were to study the implementation and discover that under certain conditions you didn't really have to synchronize, the implementation isn't part of the contract and someone could change it later, leaving your program with a bug that most likely someone like James or me will have to track down and fix years later.  :(

Comment: @ajb firstly thanks for helping, and do agree I need to obey the contract. My only question was `why is it that way`.

Comment: I don't think you correctly answered the OP's question. OP's concern revolved around unique keys, however, the need for synchronization has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @TerryLi I think he did becoz from my undertsanding non-unique keys can cause race conditions. eg: val = map.get("overlappingkey"); val++;

Comment: @JavaDeveloper There is no such thing as [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if your program is single-threaded. If your program is multi-threaded, you might need to use synchronization anyway no matter the keys are unique or not.

Comment: @TerryLi my program is not single-threaded, else i would not have asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely *do* need to use synchronization, even with unique keys, unless you are 100% guaranteed the underlying Map implementation is concurrent.

For example, there are several major errors that can & likely will occur, if you try & misuse a standard HashMap with synchronization:

1. Different keys can still hash to the same bucket -- leading to corruption of the chain, typically causing entries to be lost.
2. Collection size can become incorrect, when increments/decrements are overwritten.
3. Resize will cause corruption.

There are no shortcuts here..  any attempt to try & skip on doing it properly is only going to cost waste much time in the long run.

Hope this helps your understanding!

Answer (score 1):

Think how information is stored in the map. There is an array where keys are stored in places indexed by its hashcode. Hashcodes even for different keys K1 and K2 can clash, then, as a result of collision resolution, layout would be different depending on whether K1 or K2 was put first. Now think what would be the result if K1 and K2 are put simultaneously? Both procedures think they are first, so at best, one of keys would be erased, and as worst, the whole table structure would be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The need for synchronization does not depend on whether the keys are unique or not. You need to do synchronization when there are multiple threads or processes doing write operation at the same time.

To make a map synchronized, you can use:

```
Map syncMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(hashMap);
```

Comment: thanks but, please explain me `why is synchronization needed when keys are unqiue` , a resize is a very useful answer given by james in the same thread, but is there more to it than just resize ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper If your program is single-threaded, there is no need to  use synchronization whatsoever. It has nothing to do with unique keys.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in for answering.